# Why is my web page left-aligned on iPad?

Tags: css, ipad, margin, centering

I recently built a site and centered it using `margin: 0 auto`. I also wrapped elements in a `.wrapper` class with a width set to 960px and then had the parent element extend across the whole browser.

When I view [the Brands screen](http://www.propet.com/brands/index.php) on an iPad though, the site is left-aligned and does not extend across the whole window. Any thoughts to why this might be happening, and how to correct it?

See below for a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you’ve got a few validation errors on that page:

- http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.propet.com/brands/&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0

I suspect they might be causing the issue. If you look at the page in e.g. Chrome, you’ll see a horizontal scrollbar and space outside your wrapper `<div>` there, so the issues aren’t limited to the iPad.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added a screenshot to my original question.

Comment: The homepage doesn’t have all those validation issues (although it does have one), and it looks fine, hence I think they’re part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This works for a centered webpage with a width of 1024px:

```
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.95, maximum-scale=0.95">
```